# How i get the name of user in this foreach

Tags: laravel, foreach

This is my controller

```
$user_rank = Sprintbacklog::select('assign_user_id',DB::raw('count(*) as 
jumlah_data'))->where('id_sprint',$id)->where('finish',1)-
>groupBy('assign_user_id')->get();
```

This is foreach in blade

```
@foreach($user_rank as $name_and_finish)
<tr>
<td>{{ $name_and_finish->assign_user_id}}</td>
<td><span class="badge">{{ $name_and_finish->jumlah_data }}</span></td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like you are selecting the username, just `assign_user_id`.

Comment: yes, because in 'Sprintbacklog' nothing field name of user. the name of User in table user.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you must join the models, to access the user like

```
$user_rank = Sprintbacklog::join('users',sprintbacklogs.id_user,'=','users.id')
->where('id_sprint',$id)->where('finish',1)
->select('assign_user_id',DB::raw('count(*) as jumlah_data'))
->groupBy('assign_user_id')
->get();
```

to access the name in user table, but you need an user id at the table that you want to join with.